# Is it a good idea to call a function that returns a boolean for ng-show?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does watching a value of function call  or using that in a directive like ng-show has performance hit in terms of that function getting called each time the cycle runs ?

Is it a better approach to have just a have a boolean value determine this and keep on modifying that value in different scenarios ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the watch is a function call, it will be called on every digest cycle. The performance hit is the additional time required for making a function call and executing its body compared to reading a value from an object.

If however the body of the watched function is not taking too long to execute the difference will probably be negligible; it is not a bad practice to do it, at least from the few cases I have seen.